# How to connect on-premises TFS with Azure source code repository

Tags: azure, tfs

Is it possible to connect on-premises TFS source control to Azure Visual Studio source code repository? If so, could you please write down the steps involved?

So far I haven't found anything by googlying for the question. The only way I can think of is to write a job in the Windows task scheduler that will pick up files from on-premises source control and send them to the Azure TFS. I havent done that get but with some effort it can be done.

Is there any other straight forward way of achieving the results?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to connect TFS to VSO you can do this with the TFS Integration Tools with a two way sync. Be warned that this is a really silly thing to do and I would not recommend it.

A better solution would be to simply move to VSO. You can use a one way sync with the TFS Integration Tools or OpsHub. Once there you use VSO as the primary.

You can still install and use a local TF Build server or a local Release Management server so that you can build and deploy locally.

You can even configure AAD integration to create single sign on from your local domain.

http://nakedalm.com/use-corporate-identities-existing-vso-accounts/

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe